# Using Route53 as private DNS

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I would like to use Route53 as private DNS in order to map hosts to AWS private IP addresses.
The hosted zone we are using for testing is not declared in any registrar (company-test.com.).

The ActiveMQ server url is activemq.company-test.com and it maps to (A record) private IP address of the AMQ server. This url is only reachable by other ec2 owned by the same aws account.

My question is how to configure ec2 instances so they could reach the ActiveMQ server WITHOUT  having to buy a new domain company-test.com ?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if they're all inside the same private network then can't you just use the AMQ Server IP and the other ec2 instances would be able to see it? Can you ping the AMQ Server from those instances?

Comment: @Peter AMQ server is itself an ec2 instance and it could change it's IP if I reboot it or if I replace it with a new instance.
Besides, there's a couple of servers (Puppet, Nagios) in the same network, so maintaining client configurations that point to server private IP would be a hard & unproductive task.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an [Elastic IP](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346) to your ActiveMQ instance.

> Elastic IP addresses are static IP addresses designed for dynamic
>   cloud computing. An Elastic IP address is associated with your
>   account, not a particular instance, and you control that address until
>   you choose to explicitly release it. Unlike traditional static IP
>   addresses, however, Elastic IP addresses allow you to mask instance or
>   availability zone failures by programmatically remapping your public
>   IP addresses to any instance associated with your account.

Another option is to set up a [Virtual Private Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) (VPC), and launch your ActiveMQ instance there.  Your private IP address will not change on reboot.  Another feature of VPC is the use of [Elastic Network Interfaces](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/12/new-elastic-network-interfaces-in-the-virtual-private-cloud.html) (ENI).  You can move the interface between different instances if needed.